# How to point to Python 3 interpreter using a file name that's independent of the user name

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Platypus to convert a Python 3 script into an app that can be executed by users on Mac OS without having to use the Command Line.

The devices used by the target user group all have Python 3 and the required packages installed using anaconda in the `/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/python` directory.

Platypus asks me for the location of my Python interpreter, the file path for which contains my username. The resulting `.app` file is executable on my device, but not on other devices, because the path pointing to the interpreter contains my username and not that of the end user.

How can I avoid this problem and point to the Python 3 interpreter on each user's machine (assuming it is located at `/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/python`)?

I have attached a screenshot of the Platypus interface to illustrate where I need to enter the path pointing to the interpreter.

[image: Platypus user interface]

Comment: Usually the interpreter is defined in the shebang in the very first line of the script which is made executable:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

Comment: Have you tried replacing `/Users/username` with just `~`?

Comment: @cwallenpoole, I have. Strangely, this does not work. It produces a "missing interpreter" error saying that the interpreter `~/anaconda3/bin/python` does not exist. When I take that path (directly from the error message) and paste it at the terminal prompt it correctly starts the python command line.

Comment: Hey, I dealing with the same issue, have you found a solution